# PHP exec output text with ansi2html problem

Tags: php, bash, exec

I use ansi2html to covert colors for HTML
But when I use exec in php for run bash file, the output is not correct.

```
exec("inxi.sh 2>&1", $returnOut, $stdout);
echo $returnOut[0];
```

```
<pre style="color:#bbb;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;overflow-wrap:break-word">&#x2403;12System:    &#x2403;&#x2403;12Host&#x2403; TiTAN &#x2403;12Kernel&#x2403; 5.3.0-59-generic x86_64 &#x2403;12bits&#x2403; 64 &#x2403;12compiler&#x2403; gcc &#x2403;12v&#x2403; 9.2.1 &#x2403;12Console&#x2403; N/A &#x2403;
```

If I run bash file with terminal its return:

```
<pre style="color:#bbb;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;overflow-wrap:break-word"><span style="color:#55f">System:</span>
```

inxi.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

inxi -xxx -C -D -G -I -m -M -n -R -s -S --usb -c 2 | ansi2html -n
```

Comment: Are you positively sure that it's `ansi2html` the command that's stripping your output? `inxi` appears to be a system information tool, so it's likely that whatever user the web server runs as has less privileges than your personal user.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález `inxi` output has bash colored and I can't show it in HTML CSS so I use `ansi2html` and its work well but in the terminal, when using PHP its mess up